Build failed: java: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size)
I am trying to implement the Zuul gateway however, after adding this dependency I'm getting a build error for SpringBoot 2.2.6.
Here's the dependency I added.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
</dependency>

Error Message:

java: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file C:\Users\farheen.saif.shaikh\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.6\aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size)

For some reason, I checked other solutions but no help. I tried deleting and adding dependency back. However it didn't work, please advise.

This question is similar to: Configuring maven to check integrity checksums when downloading artifacts from repository and/or building a project?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I also have this issue. I'm not using Netflix-zuul though. I have openjdk 21.0.4 2024-07-16 LTS

The trick is to download the latest aspectj from https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/releases/tag/V1_9_22_1 and then place the jar in the existing .m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.6 location, replacing aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar but KEEPING IT'S NAME. This'll run the latest aspectjweaver but think it's still 1.8.9.
Until the parent dependencies that download 1.8.9 get updated to use a newer aspectj, you're stuck working around it :(

Also, those who are trying might face this issue because of Maven dependency not loaded completely. Make sure all your dependencies are in place.

In a project I found, remove explicit version of aspectjweaver was enough. In that specific case, version was not aligned with the one set on spring-boot-dependencies in dependencyManagement.

For me it worked to switch JVMs.
I had the issue in IntelliJ for a java21 project. The JVM was (mysteriously) changed to a Java22 JVM. When switching it back to a java21 JVM the error was gone.
